# Get Google Translate / Photos / Vision apps verified for personal use in Airtable & Make.com - How to get pass Google Domain verification

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, web-applications, airtable, make.com

I spent on this literally days hours trying to figure out how it works. I need:

Google Translate API

Google Vision API

Google Photos API

I have managed to create the API keys for all of these and it worked fine. But the issue is the keys stop working after a while because the apps are in TESTING and not published. To get published I need to verify them because of scopes they require.

I tried to publish them by adding a Privacy policy, Terms of Service page online and also done a Youtube Video and described the automation in Make and Airtable.

Submitted for verification. Few hours later, the application is rejected. It asks me to verify I am the rightful owner for domains, I assume it asks me to verify if I own Airtable and Make.

The problem is I do not own the domains. I don't own Airtable, Make.

Is it going to be enough to publish Privacy policy and Terms of Service on my own server with a domain?

Is that going to satisfy the verification requirements? Because if it is not, I am just wasting my time since I can't prove ownership of Airtable/Make.

Is there any way to get the apps working?

This is not for company, just personal use. I am trying and hoping to be able to use the Google APIs with my workflow.

Specifically, Google asking for the following:

1. An official link to your app’s Privacy Policy (OK)
2. A YouTube video showing how you plan to use the Google user data you get from scope (OK)
3. A written explanation telling Google why you need access to
   sensitive and/or restricted user data (OK)
4. All your domains verified in Google Search Console (???????)

Comment: Domains are inexpensive today. Most are less than $20 and you can even get a free domain - example: [link](https://www.freenom.com/en/freeandpaiddomains.html). Get your own domain setup as you will need that for a lot of developer-related things. All developers should know how to set up and manage a domain, DNS, website, and Email.

Comment: Thanks. Means I shouldn't try to drive a car if I don't know how to add the gas. Okay I'll try to do the domain thing.